# Firebase - App Shuts Down When User Log Out After ReOpening App

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, logout

Whenever I Open App And Login It Works Fine And Also I Can Easily Logout From App And It Sends Me Back To Login Activity.. But When I Close The App After Login And Reopen App And Then I Logout It Sends Me To Login Activity Then App Closed. Don't Know Why.

Here's The Screenshot of Logcat

[image: Logcat Error Image]

Here's The Code Which Causes Problem
SignupTabFragment.java

```
if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
    // Retrieving User Data From Firebase
    userIDFireStore = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("users").document(userIDFireStore);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            userTypeFirestore = value.getString("userType");
            if(userTypeFirestore.equals("Admin")){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),AdminHomeActivity.class));
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            if(userTypeFirestore.equals("Student")){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    public void onLogoutClick(View view) {
        // Logout
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
TabItem tabLogin,tabSignup;
ViewPager viewPager;
int nightModeFlags;
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLogin = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab_login);
    tabSignup = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab_signup);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint_backgrond);

    // To Change Constraint Layout Background in Night Mode
    nightModeFlags = constraintLayout.getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    switch(nightModeFlags){
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_bg_night);
            break;
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_bg);
            break;
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
            constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_bg);
            break;
    }


//        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Login"));
//        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign Up"));
          tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final LoginAdapter adapter = new LoginAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this,tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    // Changing Fragments When The Tab is Selected or Clicked.
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
```

Comment: Can you update your login activity code?

Comment: First, the issue is in this line `value.getString("userType")` as `value` here is null, you missed a null check on Nullable item. Second, the issue is in `SignUpTabFragment` and you've shared `SignUpFragment`, are these two same?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @LalitFauzdar  Yes I Used Fragmentation One Fragment is For Login And One is For Signup, And Combined Them To LoginActivity. And Second Thing I Already Put Condition if(firebaseAuth.getUser() != null) It Will Only Be True When There's Any User Logged In. So Basically It Should Not Executed When I Logout, And At Last value.getString("userType) I Have That Value in FireStore Database. And I Want to Separate Users Accorrding To Their userType And Send Them to Their Activity WHEN THEY OPEN APP.  And Yes ClassName is SignupTabFragment That's My Typing Mistake.

Comment: @charlie.7 Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your security rules require that the user is signed in before they can read their own document from `/users/$uid`. When you log the user out, that condition is no longer met - so your `onEvent` is called with an error.

The first problem to fix is to handle the `error` that is passed to `onEvent`. The `onEvent` always gets called with *either* a `DocumentSnapshot` or an error, and you need to handle both cases. For example:

```
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
  if (error == null) {
    userTypeFirestore = value.getString("userType");
    if(userTypeFirestore.equals("Admin")){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),AdminHomeActivity.class));
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    if(userTypeFirestore.equals("Student")){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
        getActivity().finish();
    }
  }
  else {
    Log.e("Firestore", "Error listening to user data", error);
  }
}
```

---

To prevent this error from occurring in the first place, you'll want to [remove the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before you log the user out.

Comment: But Why This Condition is No Longer Met Because When A User Logout From App And Get Back To The Login Page The Condition if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) Should Be False Because No User Now Logged in And It Should Not Even Execute The Code Inside That Condition

Comment: And One More Thing, App Just Shuts Down And When I Reopen Again It Shows Me Login Activity Completely Fine

Comment: You're attaching a permanent listener, so it listens until you remove it, or the process stops (which is why restarting works). To prevent the error, remove the listener before logging the user out.

Comment: And Can You Help Me How Do I Do That, I Mean How To Remove Listener

Comment: Thank You So Much For Showing Me Right Path! :)